# Not able to use GetItem() in dynamoDb for C#

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to get item from DYnamodb table using C#

Here is my method

```
public static dynamic Dynamodb() {
            string region = "us-east-2";
            string tableName = "RetailTestData";
            var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("awsAccessKeyId"), Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("awsSecretAccessKey"));
            var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region));
            var table = Table.LoadTable(client, tableName);
             var item=table.GetItem();
return item;
}
```

reference taken from
[Get Data from a DynamoDB Table in JSON Format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/dynamodb-json.html)

but When I am trying to use the code I am getting an error
[image]

at the end I am looking to use `item.ToJson()` method as rest of my code uses the json methods

Comment: The code you've posted in your question does not match the code in the attached image. Specifically the parameters passed to `table.GetItem()`.

Comment: I suspect that you are using a version of the C# SDK that doesn't match the [GetItem documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_DynamoDBv2_DocumentModel_Table.htm) you appear to be reading.

Comment: You should be look at the AWS Official COde Library for your code examples.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel;

AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();

Table table = Table.LoadTable(client, "test");
string pk = "123";

Document document = table.GetItem(pk);
```

Comment: how are you passing the AWS credentials while creating the dynamodb client also which nuget version you are using for AWSASDK.DynamoDb

Comment: V2 version for the .NET SDK is marked deprecated
on the AWS Github page here -- https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples

Comment: @smac2020 I didn't use V2 of the SDK?

Comment: @LeeroyHannigan 's probably using this for the documentation bits: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItemsDocumentClasses.html
Still V3 (I think) but using the `DocumentModel.Document`  classes rather than the more generic `Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>` pattern

Answer (score 1):

To get an item from Amazon DynamoDB, try using the **AWS SDK for .NET V3** (which is the recommended version of the .NET SDK).

You can use the **GetItemAsync()**. Notice that the call is an async method. If you are not familiar with AWS SDK For .NET V3 - here is the DEV Guide.

[What is the AWS SDK for .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html)

The C# code is:

```
public static async Task<Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>> GetItemAsync(AmazonDynamoDBClient client, Movie newMovie, string tableName)
        {
            var key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
            {
                ["title"] = new AttributeValue { S = newMovie.Title },
                ["year"] = new AttributeValue { N = newMovie.Year.ToString() },
            };

            var request = new GetItemRequest
            {
                Key = key,
                TableName = tableName,
            };

            var response = await client.GetItemAsync(request);
            return response.Item;
        }
```

This example and other C# examples are located in the [Official AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/dynamodb_example_dynamodb_GetItem_section.html).

Comment: This is a good method to accomplish collecting an item from Dynamo, but the return type is different, in this case `response.Item` would be of type `Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>` (SDK V3)

versus the type in the original question which would be of type `AmazonDynamoDbv2.Model.DocumentModel.Document`. (SDK V2)

Answer (score 0):

It is a little late to this question but I was going to add some clarifying bits regarding keys and documentation but @Leeroy Hannigans answer does the job.

I am using the documentation found here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItemsDocumentClasses.html

```
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel;

AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();


Table table = Table.LoadTable(client, "Music");

// You can construct you keys however you want/need to
// This just has a primary key of Music with a sort key 
// of {songName} there are other ways to construct a key,
// for this example
Primitive primaryKey = "Tenacious D"; // this is also a string
Primitive sortKey = "Tribute" // This is just a string

Document document = table.GetItem(primaryKey, sortKey);
return document.ToJson(); // converts the item to a JSON object
```

Below is a visual layout for the example above

[image: Image for Partition and sort key]